# How to send a single quote to an input element with Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium

When i send a single quote with the SendKeys() method, Selenium sends two single quotes instead. I am using C# with the Chrome Driver.

Here is my code:

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
var element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("uid"));
element.Clear();
element.SendKeys("admin'--");
```

The textbox on the tested web page receives the following value:

admin''--

How to send a single quote to an element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code sample you sent works for me.

I tried with fireFoxDriver:

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
        var element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
        element.Clear();
        element.SendKeys("one quote: ', double quote \"");
```

and the output in google search box is:

one quote: ', double quote "

try to start with the simplest example, and insert one quote by: "'"

Comment: Confirmed! Apperantly, it is a bug in the Chrome Driver. With the Firefox Driver the character is sent correctly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try escaping string with \, also remember to use verbatim @ symbol

```
element.SendKeys(@"admin\'--\'");
```

Comment: I already tried escaping with element.SendKeys("admin\'--'"); This has the same result unfortunately.

Comment: try and see if if this is helpful, I did not test that,:)
  textArea.click();
  textArea.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.END));
  textArea.sendKeys(replyText);
  ReplyButton.click();

Answer (score 0):

I also think it is related to ChromeDriver as it worked on Firefox. Anyways I have used the JavaScript for this and it worked.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("id"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].value="test'w";", element);
```